# Unable to remove a ppa, which doesn't support my Ubuntu's version. ppa-purge isn't working too

Tags: ppa, purge, flatpak

I added a flatpak ppa repository which doesn't supports my ubuntu's version (21.10). How to delete it from my system?

ppa-purge is also not working in this case:

```
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:flatpak/stable
[sudo] password for mihir: 
Updating packages lists
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
```

Comment: Hello. Did you not just ask this almost exact same question a little while ago?

Comment: It was deleted. I think the person who thought that it's a duplicate question, and provided the link to original question. But the linked question did not had the solution to my issue. That's why I asked it again.

Comment: Try the other method. Go to the sources list and remove the entry for this bad PPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command removed the repo:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:flatpak/stable
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the PPA repository file:

```
sudo ls /etc/apt/sources.d/
```

and simply remove that file.
For instance, on my machine I have:

```
google-chrome.list
google-chrome.list.save
```

I'd then remove both.
Also check to see if your PPA is included in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.save`, if it is, simply remove it.

Comment: ls: cannot access '/etc/apt/sources.d/': No such file or directory

Comment: What command did you use to install your PPA? Can you add that to your question? It looks like you might want to try looking inside your `/etc/apt/sources.list`